# WebStorm debugging React-Native async function

Tags: react-native, async-await, webstorm

I noticed that setting breakpoints on async function stops the debugger and doesn't work.

This is the sample code that I'm trying to debug:

```js
console.log("getMnemonicPhrase")
const result = await function_async()
console.log("result")
```

This is the async function:

```js
async function_async() {
    return await function({})
}
```

The debugger works before calling the async function, when it reach this line, it stops.

Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don‘t know a better solution than adding `debugger`

```js
async function_async() {
    debugger
    return await function({})
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that I had problems with my code and the execution stopped before the async task.